# Appbar title under status bar flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am relatively new to flutter so I don't know why my appbar appears like this
[image: app screenshot]

Here is the main.dart file

```
import 'package:testapp/test_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(Home());
}


class Home extends 
StatelessWidget {

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext 
context) {
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Test App',
  theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.purple),
  home: TestPage(),
);
}
}
```

Here is my testpage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends 
StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext 
context) {
return Scaffold(
  primary: false,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(' Test app'),
  ),
  body: Center(child: Text('Example Test')),
);
}
}
```

I tried using SafeArea it didn't work. Thank you

Comment: wrap with safe area widget

Comment: I tried adding safe area, it didn't work

Comment: Can you just convert `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget`..not sure if it works..just give it a try..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you much guys, I created a new project then I realised it was caused by a bug from one of the libraries I installed. It's totally fixed now ♥️

Answer (score 3):

here is how i solved similar issue.
Simply wrap your Scaffold widget with SafeArea Widget

```
SafeArea(
   child: Scaffold()
)
```

You can find more detail about SafeArea Widget in this link
[Flutter SafeArea Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html)

Hope it will help

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

change the primary value to true and tell me result:

```
Scaffold(
primary: true, // this line
appBar: AppBar(......
```

**Edit:**

MaterialApp cant be a child of statelessWidget. use it as the main Widget

```
runApp(MaterialApp(
  ......
))
```

Comment: I didn't work, i set it to false while I was trying to fix the problem with it

Comment: `MaterialApp` can be child of stateless widget.

Answer (score 0):

You have primary property set to false.

> Whether this scaffold is being displayed at the top of the screen.
>
> If true then the height of the appBar will be extended by the height
>   of the screen's status bar, i.e. the top padding for MediaQuery.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/primary.html

Comment: I didn't work, i set it to false while I was trying to fix the problem with it

Comment: it should work. retry stopping and then running the app instead of hot-reload.

Comment: if this does not work, try posting `styles.xml` from android folder.